# How to hide some fields on insert and edit pages, in dynamic data website?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I want to hide some fields, so that the user can't put value for them on insert and edit pages, and I will give these fields default values on code behind later.

I want to hide these fields just in insert pages but want to see them on the list pages, such as the createdAt column.

How to do this?

Comment: can you provide more details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve Naughton at c# bits has a way of doing this using a useful extension to DD sites :
See [this](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2010/02/new-way-to-do-column-generation-in.html)